# Why we can't print particular line of text file with this method?

Tags: python, list, loops, file, readfile

We can use file like a list on loops and each line of text looks like element of list. But we cant print particular line of text file with 'print(fhandle[0])'. Im beginner and i cant understand this. Can u explain to me?

```
fhandle = open('TestTXT.txt')

for line in fhandle:
    print(line)

print(fhandle[0])
```

Terminal Screenshot:
[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Comment: Because it isn't designed for that. There isn't a way to know where in the file a given line begins, except to read the file until enough newlines have been seen. Because this could take arbitrarily long (depending on how long the file is and what index you want) for an indexing operation (supposed to be fast and take the same amount of time no matter what), the operation is not provided.

Comment: The object reference returned by open() is of type _io.TextIOWrapper which is iterable. That's how/why it works in the for loop. It is not indexable